# Question about Set Notation and Minimization: $\colon, \mid$

Tags: notation

I see many different notations in context of sets, minimization.

For example

$$\min_{x \in X} f(x),$$

$$\min \{ f(x) \mid x \in X \}$$

$$\min \{ f(x) \colon x \in X\}$$

and so on..

Is there any difference between them? I feel very confused when I read books on optimization and they use these things very inconsistently.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nope, all the same.

Answer (score 1):

No, all these notations express exactly the same thing. The only difference that you might want to be aware of is between $$\arg\min_{x\in X} f(x)$$ and $$\min_{x\in X}f(x)$$ or it's equivalent forms that you refer to in your post. The $\arg\min$ refers to the $x_0 \in X$ at which the minimum of $f$ is attained and the $\min$ refers to the minimum value of the function $f$ which is in that case $f(x_0)\in \mathbb R$.

Otherwise, all the expressions that you have above are equivalent.